# Grails render PDF with a specific layout and multiple pages?

Tags: pdf, grails, pdf-generation, rendering

i need to generate pdf files in a specific layout with support for multiple pdf pages etc.. I can imagine that i could render gsp output to a pdf but how can i handle the concept of multiple pages? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i am using flying saucer, through the rendering plugin: http://www.grails.org/plugin/rendering

For multiple pages, use some CSS2 like:

```
@page {
  size: 210mm 297mm; // A4 format 
  @bottom-center { content: element(footer);} // if you want footer
  @top-center { content: element(header); } // if you want header
}

div.break {
  page-break-after:always;
}
```

Then you will have a page break each time you use `<div class="break"/>`
your header will be into `<div id="header"/>` and your footer into `<div id="footer"/>`